# Elastic Beanstalk environment variables are reachable from api routes but not client pages when using Next.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This my first time making a post on StackOverflow, so forgive me if my question isn't structured in the best way.

I have a Next.js web app hosted on Elastic Beanstalk, and I'm running into a strange issue where my Elastic Beanstalk instance is able to access **process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE** fine on the endpoints, but returns **undefined** when attempting to access it from one of the front-end pages.

I tried console logging **process.env** in one of my frontend pages (pages/SignUpPage), but it only returned **{}**.

I did the same console log on a test endpoint I created (pages/api/testEnv) and got back a populated json object with all the environment variables and their values.

It's weird because the client pages can access process.env fine on localhost:3000, but fails to do so on EB.

I made to sure to check the environment properties in the configuration options of the EB instance, but everything is set up in the same way as my .env.local. Environment variables that I'm trying to access from the front-end pages are also prefixed with **NEXT_PUBLIC_** as instructed by the Next.js docs.

I'm struggling to find any information regarding this issue, so I kind of get the feeling that I'm missing something obvious here. I would really appreciate it if someone could provide some insight on this issue!

Comment: Hi @AaronLee
Did you find any solution. I'm facing the same issue